# How to UNHEX() MySQL binary string in C# .NET?

Tags: c#, mysql, string

I need to use HEX() in MySQL to get data out of the database and process in C# WinForm code. The binary string needs to be decoded in C#, is there an equivalent UNHEX() function?

From MySQL Doc:

> For a string argument str, HEX() returns a hexadecimal string
>   representation of str where each byte of each character in str is
>   converted to two hexadecimal digits. (Multi-byte characters therefore
>   become more than two digits.) The inverse of this operation is
>   performed by the UNHEX() function.
>
> For a numeric argument N, HEX() returns a hexadecimal string
>   representation of the value of N treated as a longlong (BIGINT)
>   number. This is equivalent to CONV(N,10,16). The inverse of this
>   operation is performed by CONV(HEX(N),16,10).
>
> mysql> SELECT 0x616263, HEX('abc'), UNHEX(HEX('abc'));
>           -> 'abc', 616263, 'abc' mysql> SELECT HEX(255), CONV(HEX(255),16,10);
>           -> 'FF', 255

Comment: You're asking for hex, but your title is "Unhex" ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this not-widely-known `SoapHexBinary` class to parse hex string

```
string hex = "616263";
var byteArr = System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001.SoapHexBinary.Parse(hex).Value;
var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

After fetching the binary string from the database, you can "unhex" it this way:

```
public static string Hex2String(string input)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < input.Length; i+=2){ //throws an exception if not properly formatted
        string hexdec = input.Substring(i, 2);
        int number = Int32.Parse(hexdec, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        char charToAdd = (char)number;
        builder.Append(charToAdd);
    }
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

The method builds a string from the hexadecimal format of the numbers, their char representation being concatenated to the builder branch.